# Do not log access to some php scripts

Tags: nginx, php, logging

I would like to exclude from access.log access to some php scripts.
To do this, I did the following:

```
 location ~ ^/lib/exe/(jquery|taskrunner|css|js)\.php$ {
        access_log off; 
        #access_log /var/log/nginx/test_access.log;
        try_files /dev/null/1 @processphp;
    }   

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files /dev/null/1 @processphp;
    }   

    location @processphp {
        if (!-f $request_filename) { return 404; }
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param REDIRECT_STATUS 200;
    
        # send to fastcgi
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;    
    }
```

But unfortunately, it didn't work.
`/lib/exe/jquery.php`
`/lib/exe/js.php`
`/lib/exe/css.php`
`/lib/exe/taskrunner.php`
are still in access.log.

Tell me please, how can I do what I want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I managed to do it!

```
http {
...
    map $request_filename $log {
        default 1;
       "~/(jquery|js|css|taskrunner)\.php" 0;
    }
...

server {
    ...
    location ~ \.php$ {
            access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log combined if=$log;
            if (!-f $request_filename) { return 404; }
            include fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            fastcgi_param REDIRECT_STATUS 200;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
            include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    }
...
```

But I will be glad if someone offers a better option!

Docs:

- http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_log_module.html#access_log
- https://www.nginx.com/blog/sampling-requests-with-nginx-conditional-logging/

Comment: In "Original Case" , you have `/lib/exe/(...)` , while in "New Case" , you have `~/(...)` : You could try the Same in "Original Case" too , it should then work.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).